# First letter of the word in formular field uppercase?

Tags: html

The default form of writing in formular field words is lowercase. I want that the first letter of word begins with Uppercase and than other letters lowercase. How can I format this in formular field ?

Comment: What are you meaning by "formular field", do you mean form text inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the first character to be capitalized you can introduce some javascript (jQuery). Like this:

```
$( '#targetInput' ).keyup(function() {
    $(this).val(function(i, text) {
        return text.substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + text.substr(1);
    });
});
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8x8cs76m/

Comment: You can also make this a function and then in the inputs do ´<input type="text" onkeydown="capItPlz()">´